# How to create a blank Jupyter notebook using ein?

Tags: ein, jupyter

I am using `ein` package in Emacs, and everything works fine when I use an existing Jupyter file.
However, when I create a new `.ipynb` file (with `C-x C-f`), I get a blank buffer which doesn't have any cell.

I tried adding cell above/below (`C-c C-a` - as I can do in existing files), but it says that it is undefined.

How can I create a blank Jupyter notebook with a blank cell?

Answer (score 0):

To get this

***`ein` Dashboard***

[image: ein dashboard]

I did this

This is the list of packages I have installed on `debian`

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep jupyter
ii  jupyter-core                                       4.11.1-1                             all          Core common functionality of Jupyter projects (tools)
ii  python3-jupyter-client                             7.3.4-1                              all          Jupyter protocol client APIs (Python 3)
ii  python3-jupyter-core                               4.11.1-1                             all          Core common functionality of Jupyter projects for Python 3
```

The latest version of `ein` from `git` checkout wasn't compiling with `emacs` 29.0.50 (`master` branch).  So my `ein` is checked out at this commit

```
~/src/nongnu-elpa/packages/ein$ git log --format=oneline | head -n 1
bfd04d3175cfb72f2e3a20eb034f8d6825a2a906 emacs28 changes
```

I start `jupyter notebook` from the terminal with

```
/usr/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/home/whitetrillium/src/data/ --no-browser
```

The output in the `terminal` gives you the `port` number and `token`.

```
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/whitetrillium/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-267275-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=a7483254e295e6759ec8acb77a492fd98c9c26f9cc78829c
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=a7483254e295e6759ec8acb77a492fd98c9c26f9cc78829c
```

Then once when I do `M-x ein:login`, `ein` prompts me for the `port` number and the `password`.  Once the login goes through, I see the above dashboard, which allows me to open existing notebooks or create new notebooks, or stop the running notebooks.